# I don't want to see all the graphs before selecting a dropdown button (python plotly)

Tags: python, button, drop-down-menu, plotly, plotly-python

I created a dropdown menu with several graphs and everything is fine but when I start the program and have not yet selected one of the buttons, I see all the graphs and it just looks messy so I want to change this. In the default situation I would like to see only the graph that is connected to the first button. I tried to do this with the line "active = 0" but it only caused the first button to be highlighted.

Here is a snippet of my data (it shows the effect of the corona crisis on the sales index in the german manufacturing industry):

```
Chemicals;Mechanical engineering;Motor vehicles and motor vehicle parts;Dates
101.5;108.1;104.6;Jan-2019
101.2;105.8;105.9;Feb-2019
101;105.9;106.2;Mar-2019
101;105.6;101.2;Apr-2019
99.3;103.2;104.5;Mai-2019
99.4;103;101.9;Jun-2019
99.2;104;99.5;Jul-2019
99.4;103;102.2;Aug-2019
97.1;102.7;102.2;Sept-2019
99.7;100.6;100.9;Okt-2019
99.1;101.8;100.4;Nov-2019
98.7;99.7;101.6;Dez-2019
99.2;102.4;100.1;Jan-2020
101.5;100.1;99.8;Feb-2020
99.2;91.5;72.7;Mar-2020
90;73.9;24.8;Apr-2020
```

And here is a simple version of my program:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sales_index_manufacturing.csv", delimiter = ";")

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df['Dates']),
               y=list(df['Chemicals']),
               name="Chemicals",
               line=dict(color="#008b8b"))
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df['Dates']),
               y=list(df['Mechanical engineering']),
               name='Mechanical engineering',
               line=dict(color="#8b008b"))
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df['Dates']),
               y=list(df['Motor vehicles and motor vehicle parts']),
               name='Motor vehicles and motor vehicle parts',
               line=dict(color="#ffa500"))
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active= 0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label='Chemicals',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True,False,False]},
                           {"title": "Chemicals",
                            "annotations": [],
                           'yaxis': {'title': 'sales index (2015 = 100)'}}]),
                dict(label='Mechanical engineering',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False,True,False]},
                           {"title": 'Mechanical engineering',
                            "annotations": [],
                           'yaxis': {'title': 'sales index (2015 = 100'}}]),
                dict(label='Motor vehicles and motor vehicle parts',
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False,False,True]},
                           {"title": "Motor vehicles and motor vehicle parts",
                            "annotations": [],
                           'yaxis': {'title': 'sales index (2015 = 100)'}}]
                    )]
            ),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=-0.04,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.132,
            yanchor="top",
        )
    ])


fig.update_layout(
    legend=dict(x= 0.75,
                y=1.1,
                bgcolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                bordercolor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'),
    width=1000,
    height=600,
    autosize=False,
    template="plotly_white",
)

fig.show()
```

When you run the code, you're probably wondering what I mean by "messy," but the original program contains a lot more graphs and data, and it really looks like a mess in the default situation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You've only included `fig.update_layout`. How you've built your fig will most likely also be of importance. So please include a runnable code snippet with a sample of your data so we can help you better.

Comment: @vestland I just added a complete program and a short dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Lucie please share your df as `df.head(10).to_dict()`